# how i can make a php page that adds data to the database and if the data already exists to deletes it instead?

Tags: php, mysql

how i can make a php page that adds values to the database, and if the value already exist to delete it instead of add it?
I am trying to do it but i am making a mistake and it only "deletes values".

```
<?php
require("database.php");
if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    echo "error";
} else {
    $cdtitle=$_POST["cds"];
    $cdartist=$_POST["kal"];
    $query= 'SELECT FROM cds WHERE cdtitle=:cdtitle && cdartist=:cdartist';
    $result = $sql->prepare($query);
    $result->execute([":cdtitle" => $cdtitle, ":cdartist" => $cdartist]);
    $a = $result->fetchAll();

    if ($a>0) {
        $cdtitle=$_POST["cds"];
        $cdartist=$_POST["kal"];
        $query= 'DELETE FROM cds WHERE cdtitle=:cdtitle && cdartist=:cdartist';
        $result = $sql->prepare($query);
        $result->execute([":cdtitle" => $cdtitle, ":cdartist" => $cdartist]);
        $a = $result->fetchAll();
        echo "Deleted!";
    } else {
        $add = "INSERT INTO cds(username, cdtitle, cdartist) VALUES (:username, :cdtitle, :cdartist)";
        $result = $sql->prepare($add);
        $result->execute([":username" => $username ,":cdtitle" => $cdtitle, ":cdartist" => $cdartist]);
        $result->fetchAll();
        echo "Added!";
    }
}
?>
```

ok where is my mistake? how i can make it this way that it will add the value to the database if it doesn't exists and it will delete the value from the database if it exist?

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: When i run it it were only deletes the data, if the data doesn't exists it will still try to delete it instead of adding it. btw the question is answered. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no column in the query you are selected.

Add * to select all.

```
$query= 'SELECT * FROM cds WHERE cdtitle=:cdtitle && cdartist=:cdartist';
```

Then you can add query to count.

```
$sqlCount = 'SELECT count(*) FROM cds WHERE cdtitle=:cdtitle && cdartist=:cdartist';

$exe = $conn->prepare($sqlCount);
$exe->execute([":cdtitle" => $cdtitle, ":cdartist" => $cdartist]);
$count = $exe->fetchColumn();
```

Then change if condition to.

```
if($count > 0)
```